# Child element's width is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

code:

```
$(".article-image").each(function(){
    var imgW = $(this).children("img").naturalWidth;
    console.log(imgW);
})
```

`$(this).children("img”).length` is 1, however imgW is undefined.

I've also tried:

```
$(this).children("img").scrollWidth;
```

And this was 0:

```
$(this).children("img").width();
```

Comment: Is the image loaded? Have you got any onload listener? Or you are making this in the document ready? (in this last case doesn't works, even img.length is equal to 1)

Comment: Perhaps you could use find instead of children?

Comment: @User your problem is the `load` event in the images. You aren't reading the width **after** image has been loaded. I insist you, give us more details

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to read the image width before it loaded. So this is what I did:

```
$(".article-image").each(function(){
    $(this).children("img").load(function(){
        var imgH = $(this).parent().children("img").height();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `outerWidth`

```
$(".article-image").each(function(){
   var imgW = $(this).children("img").outerWidth;
   console.log(imgW);
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$(this).find("img").eq(0).css("width");
```

If you need width of specific element, you can give the element class name:

```
$(this).find(".className").css("width");
```

Comment: `$(this).find("img").eq(0).css("width");` says 0px;

Comment: I checked your site, you may get zero because you calc the width before the img src loaded so the width is zero

Comment: How do I wait until it's loaded?